# How to set default content of input of type month?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Is it possible to change the default content of this element: (Using Google Chrome)

```
<input type="month"/>
```

To make it, for instance, a blank field (default display)?

Comment: You want the entire field to be blank?

Comment: Just use a normal text field?

Comment: @JamesWalker, I should not let the user fill the input box

Comment: @Charlie, yes that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: The comment “I should not let the user fill the input box” raises the question why you are using an `input` element in the first place. And an `input type=month` element has no value by default, so it is not clear what you mean by wanting a “blank field”. In a word, it is impossible to tell what is being asked (and the accepted answer just gives some unrelated alternatives, so we cannot infer the question from the answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to make the input field entirely blank, that is without the hyphens.

> Is it possible to change the default content...

You can, however, change the default date shown through the `value` attribute:

```
<input type="month" value="1963-12" />
```

[This will display December, 1963](http://jsfiddle.net/wBV7B/1/) (oh what a night...)

Note that the month must be two characters, 0 padded for less than 10.

I would suggest reading up on the [other attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.month.html) that let you customize the field further.

If you really want to show an entirely blank field, I would suggest using a blank `input` tag and writing your own functionality to style and format the date within it.

Comment: +1 for Yacht Rock reference. Is there a badge for that?

Comment: @Will No, but there should be a "Four Seasons" badge that can only be awarded in scenarios like this.

Comment: <a class="badge">• Piña Colada<a>!